# Recursive relationship and nested eager loading with constraints

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm tryng to create nested eager loading with a where constraint on a recursive relationship

Models and query simulation:

Model Hierarchy

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Hierarchy extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hierarchy';
    protected  $primaryKey = 'id_hierarchy';

    protected $fillable = [        
        'name',
        'parent_id'
    ];

    /**
     * @return HasMany 
     * 
     * This method implement recursive relationship
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Hierarchy::class, 'parent_id')->with('children');
    }

    /**
    * @return HasMany
    */
    public function grandchildren()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Grandchild::class, 'id_hierarchy');        
    }
}
```

Model Grandchild

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grandchild extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'grandchildren';
    protected  $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [        
        'id_hierarchy',
        'id_something'
        'name'
    ];

     /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function hierarchy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hierarchy::class, 'id_hierarchy');
    }

}
```

The following query does not return the grandchildren as it was supposed to;

```
 public function read($id) 
{

   $data = Hierarchy::query()
           ->whereNull('parent_id')
           ->with(['children.grandchildren' => function ($query) use($id)  {
                  $query->where('id_something',  $id);
           }])
           ->get();
}
```

The problem is in the constrain, because with the following query it returns the grandchildrren (although not filtered because it doesn't have the where condition)

```
$data = Hierarchy::query()
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with(['children.grandchildren'])
        ->get();
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions to resolve this issue.

Edited:

As the code is a simulation of the real case, I added 'id_something' to be clearer what is involved.

'id_something' is related to another model that is not represented here

Comment: What is the value of `$id` coming as parameter to `read($id)` I mean does it represent an id of `GrandChild` records or `Hierarchy` (children)  records?

Comment: @Donkarnash sorry, the case wasn't clear enough. I added 'id_something' to make it clearer

Comment: But this `id_something` belongs to which table `hierarchy` or `grandchildren`?

Comment: It belongs to a model that is not represented in the example. In the real case the equivalent of the Grandchild model is related to multiple other models and the returned data needs to be filtered by the equivalent of the id of one of those models.

Comment: That's the issue if `id_something` is not a column on `grandchildren` table the `$query->where('id_something',  $id);` will return no results or would actually throw exception.  If you want to filter `grandchildren` records by comparing `columnName` of one it's related models with some value received via request, then it should be done differently

Comment: Thanks. 'id_something is a column of the grandchildren table and is also the primary key, for example, of a table named home_city.
What I want with constrain is to get all the grandchildren who live in a certain home_city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `HomeCity` is one of the related models for `GrandChild` and the relationship is defined as

```php
//GrandChild.php
public function home_city()
{
    return $this->hasMany(HomeCity::class);
}
```

Then the query to return `GrandChild` records who live in `HomeCity` (`id_something` is a column on `home_city` table) identified by `$id` may written as:

```php
public function read($id) 
{

   $data = Hierarchy::query()
           ->whereNull('parent_id')
           ->with(['children' => function ($query) use($id)  {
               $query->with(['grandchildren' => function($query) use($id) {
                   $query->whereHas('home_city', fn($query) => $query->where('id_something',  $id);
               }]);                  
           }])
           ->get();
}
```